# Replace each element in a list

Tags: groovy

Here is how to transform a Zorglub (it is an API that I can not modify):

```
Zorglub transformedZorglub = zorglub.transform()
```

I am given a `java.util.List<Zorglub>` and I must transform them all, then afterwards I will perform more operations on the transformed Zorglubs. After transformation I never use the originals anymore. This question is only about the transformation part. I wrote this:

```
List<Zorglub> transformedZorglubs = new ArrayList<Zorglub>(zorglubs.size())
zorglubs.each {
    transformedZorglubs.add(
        it.transform()
    )
}
zorglubs = transformedZorglubs
```

Is there something smarter or more elegant to do?

In particular, something that would avoid creating a new list and using twice as much memory, while avoiding bugs that often arise when modifying a list while iterating over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the elements in-place without building a new list,
you would need to reassign the elements at each index, that is,
essentially `zorglubs[i] = zorglubs[i].transform()` for each index `i` in the list.

A perhaps elegant way to do this is using the `eachWithIndex` function,
which gives you access to each element and its index:

```
zorglubs.eachWithIndex { it, index -> zorglubs[index] = it.transform() }
```

Answer (score 1):

`zorglubs = zorglubs.collect{it.transform()}` will a bit more elegantly but actually `collect` returns new array.